# Laravel default helper method and facade doesn't work on custom package

Tags: php, laravel, package

I am developing a custom package where I need an access to the config data. I was able to pull data from config through my blade files, however, when I tried to call it from any custom classes I made, it's throwing an error:

> Error: Call to undefined function Acme\Package\config()

What's interesting though, is that, when I tried using the facade `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config`, it cannot find the class.

Is there any way I could retrieve data from the config (from the package and/or the app)?

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Package;

class MyClass {
    public function test() {
        config('app.name');
    }
}
```

UPDATE: It works when running in the browser (package installed in a Laravel project) but fails when running package's test

UPDATE: If this helps, my package can be found [here](https://github.com/silverxjohn/plate)

Call to the `config()` is from [here](https://github.com/silverxjohn/plate/blob/master/src/Forms/Blueprint.php#L24)

And the test case that fails can be found [here](https://github.com/silverxjohn/plate/blob/master/tests/Unit/FormBuilderTest.php#L61)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Package;

class MyClass {
    public function test() {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::get('app.name');
    }
}
```

Try like this, to use the full namespace to the Config Facade. You could also make a `use` statement under your namespace to inject the facade and then use `Config::get('app.name)`. The reason it is not working is that your package cannot resolve the namespace of that facade as it is outside of the IoC container

Comment: I tried your recommendation. It still failing.

> Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config' not found

Comment: I also tried resolving the `Config` class through app make, but it cannot find the `app()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<?php

    namespace Acme\Package;
    use Config;

    class MyClass {
        public function test() {
            Config::get('app.name');

        }
    }
```

**Updated answer**

Please add below line in `config/app.php` in `aliases` section

```
'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
```

then run below command

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation. It still failing

> Error: Class 'Config' not found

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. Tried clearing caches but no luck. It's working when the package is installed in a Laravel application. However, it doesn't work when used as a 'standalone'. By 'standalone, I meant running in phpunit. My guess is that the autoload doesn't include the laravel's

Comment: Have updated the question. Maybe you can take a look? Thanks!